# Is the Kotlin "if" keyword actually a function?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin when you write something like

```
if (true) {
  doStuff()
}
```

is `{}` actually a lambda expression, not a block? Therefore you can think of `if` as a function that takes a lambda as the second argument and executes it if its first argument is true (pseudocode):

```
fun if(checkIfThisIsTrue: Boolean?, runThisLambdaIfTheFirstArgIsTrue: (T) -> T)
```

Reminds me of how Ruby doesn't have arithmetic, `2 + 3` is actually syntax sugar for `2.+(3)` where `+` is the name of a method on the object named `2`. Is Kotlin also designed in this manner (e.g. `{}` *always* means a lambda), or can `{}` not mean a lambda?

Comment: `2+3` in Kotlin is indeed `2.plus(3)` and same goes for multiply, division, and subtraction. `a += 3` is also `a.plusAssign(3)` and many more methods with `operator` keyword in front of them. But I'm Important pretty sure `if` is not a lambda accepting function. You can see this if you do `Ctrl+leftclick` on operator/function callsite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a lambda expression or a function. According to the [kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#if-expression):

> In Kotlin, if is an expression, i.e. it returns a value.

and the documentation about [functional programming](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/functional-programming.html#function-literals-lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions):

> Note that the other uses of curly braces in Kotlin, such as in function and class definitions and after if/else/for/while statements, are not lambda expressions (so it is not the case that if is a function that conditionally executes a lambda function

How the if statement is constructed and then finally interpreted is described in the [grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#ifExpression):

```
ifExpression (used by primaryExpression)
  : 'if' '(' expression ')'
    (controlStructureBody | ';')
  | 'if' '(' expression ')'
    controlStructureBody? ';'? 'else' (controlStructureBody | ';')
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not a function. It's handled lexically by the Kotlin compiler.

I'm no expert on the Kotlin compiler, but [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f1d9177112a9f47176104d591fb7e48a41f7017a/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/types/expressions/ControlStructureTypingVisitor.java#L86) appears to be the Java implementation.

The expression appears to be represented conceptually in code by [`KtIfExpression`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/c734069cde447329c3d958513a006eff853448ed/compiler/psi/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/psi/KtIfExpression.java).